# Regullar Expressions - Here or there?

Tags: regex

I have a file with data that resembles the following structure:

```
    {
        "HRP1001_ObjectType": "S",
        "HRP1001_ObjectID": 20000499,
        "HRP1001_BeginDate": "01.01.2017",
        "HRP1001_EndDate": "",
        "HRP1001_SubType": "B007",
        "HRP1001_TypeOfRelatedObject": "C",
        "HRP1001_IDOfRelatedObject": 30000018
    },
    {
        "HRP1001_ObjectType": "S",
        "HRP1001_ObjectID": 20000500,
        "HRP1001_BeginDate": "01.01.2017",
        "HRP1001_EndDate": "",
        "HRP1001_SubType": "A003",
        "HRP1001_TypeOfRelatedObject": "O",
        "HRP1001_IDOfRelatedObject": 10000097
    },
    {
        "HRP1001_ObjectType": "S",
        "HRP1001_ObjectID": 20000500,
        "HRP1001_BeginDate": "01.01.2017",
        "HRP1001_EndDate": "",
        "HRP1001_SubType": "A012",
        "HRP1001_TypeOfRelatedObject": "O",
        "HRP1001_IDOfRelatedObject": 10000097
    },
```

So I need to find all entities (an entity being the data between curly parenthesis) where either ObjectID has a specific value *or* IDOfRelatedObject has a specific value.

Lets say the value I am looking for is: 10000097 .I currently achieve this by running the following 2 expressions, like an idiot:

```
\{\s.*\n.*: .*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*10000097\n.*\}
\{\s.*\n.*: 10000097.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\}
```

Is there anyway to either say OR for the expressions seen above in one expression or create a smarter expression that will do the same thing?

I am using sublime text 3 btw, if the regex engine is important.. I guess it uses python, not sure..

Comment: Why the hell do you vote to close, closer? How is this question too broad? And it has been like 30 seconds since I asked the question, when did you even read it?

Comment: @revo Yes it is json but the question is about regex. This is just to give a concrete, clean example.. It might be XML later..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex's `|` OR or alternative operator.

```
\{[^{}]*"HRP1001_(ObjectID|IDOfRelatedObject)":\s*10000097[^{}]*\}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/l2ppVq/1)

Comment: I will accept it once I can. Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
{\n\s{8}\"\w+\": \"(\w+)\"\,\n\s{8}\"\w+\": \d{1,}\,\n\s{8}\"\w+\": \"\w+\.\w+.\w+\"\,\n\s{8}\"\w+\": \"\"\,\n\s{8}\"\w+\": \"\w+\"\,\n\s{8}\"\w+\": \"\w+\"\,\n\s{8}\"HRP1001_IDOfRelatedObject\": 10000097\n\s{4}\}\,
```

[enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/j2rwVh/1)